# Python NLTK: Stanford NER tagger error message: NLTK was unable to find the java file

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Trying to get Stanford NER working with Python. Followed some instructions on the web, but got the error message: "NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable." What was wrong? Thank you!

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

model = r'C:\Stanford\NER\classifiers\english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
jar = r'C:\Stanford\NER\stanford-ner-3.9.1.jar'

ner_tagger = StanfordNERTagger(model, jar, encoding = 'utf-8')

text = 'While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus ' \
       'efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

words = word_tokenize(text)
classified_words = ner_tagger.tag(words)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on the web. Replace the path with your own.

> ```
>  import os
>
>  java_path = "C:/../../jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java.exe"   
>  os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
> ```

or:

> ```
> import nltk
>
> nltk.internals.config_java('C:/../../jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java.exe')
> ```

Source: https://tianyouhu.wordpress.com/2016/09/01/problem-of-nltk-with-stanfordtokenizer/