# NLTK unable to find java.exe (spontaneous path reduction)

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp, file-not-found

Similar questions were posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866988/python-nltk-stanford-ner-tagger-error-message-nltk-was-unable-to-find-the-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202097/nltk-was-unable-to-find-the-java-file-for-stanford-pos-tagger), and my question is actually based on what was suggested in answers to those questions.

I try to parse some German texts using Stanford Parser and NLTK.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser
import os
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] ='C:\PretestKorpus\stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = 'C:\PretestKorpus\stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17'
parser=StanfordParser(model_path="C:\PretestKorpus\germanPCFG.ser.gz")
new=list(parser.raw_parse("Es war einmal ein Bauer"))
```

Then, of course, I get `NLTK was unable to find the java file!` error:

So I set configurations like this:

```
nltk.internals.config_java('C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe')
```

but it returns

```
NLTK was unable to find the C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251in\java.exe file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
```

So, somehow Python reduces the path `\\jre1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe` to `\\jre1.8.0_251in\java.exe`

Looks like this:

[image]

Setting environment variable does not help either (returns `NLTK was unable to find the java file!`error). Obviously, python does not read the path correctly. But for what reason and how to fix that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: looks like `\b` is being use as a special character, try to escape the \ before the b

Comment: @AmirSchnell but how? Yes, placing .exe into jre1.8.0_251 folder directly does not return error, but there is an error after I start parsing `new=list(parser.raw_parse("Es war einmal ein Bauer"))` - `NLTK was unable to find the java file!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python `\b` inside a String is resolved to a backspace character. Therefore you see the white *BS* in the picture, becuase the console tries to represent this special character (BS for backspace).

What you need to do is to escape the \ inside your String like so

```
nltk.internals.config_java('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_251\\bin\\java.exe')
```

It is a good practice to alway escape all backslash characters, so you can be sure that problems like this one never occur.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion and an answer to my question, however, if use configuration, it still returns `NLTK was unable to find the java file!` after `new=list(parser.raw_parse("Es war einmal ein Bauer"))` But! It returns different error after using `'JAVAHOME'` environment variable (`Java command failed`). But I assume this is an other problem.